# Loopback hasManyThrough relation for user

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have such models:

Team

```
{
  "name": "Team",
  "plural": "teams",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "ModelRest": {}
  },
  "hidden": [
    "deleted"
  ],
  "filtered": [
    "userId",
    "archived"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "deleted": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "projects": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Project"
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user"
    },
    "users": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "User",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "through": "TeamMember"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

TeamMember

```
{
  "name": "TeamMember",
  "plural": "team-members",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user"
    },
    "team": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Team"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

user

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "mixins": {
    "ModelRest": {}
  },
  "hidden": [
    "realm",
    "emailVerified",
    "lastIP",
    "deleted",
    "utmSource",
    "utmMedium",
    "utmCampaign"
  ],
  "readOnly": [
    "statusId",
    "lastListId",
    "teamId",
    "subscriptionStart",
    "subscriptionExpiration",
    "apiKey"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "username"
      }
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "min": 5
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "subscriptionStart": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "subscriptionExpiration": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "teamId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "sharePlan": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "shareLeads": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "timezone": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "utmSource": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "utmMedium": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "utmCampaign": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastIP": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "deleted": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "team": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Team"
    },
    "plan": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Plan"
    },
    "billingCycle": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "BillingCycle"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Card"
    },
    "lastList": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "List"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Status"
    },
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "AccessToken"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I've created relation in Team model:

```
"users": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "User",
  "foreignKey": "",
  "through": "TeamMember"
}
```

But **users** relation in Team doesn't work at all. In API explorer I see

*GET /teams/{id}/user*

there is no

*GET /teams/{id}/user**s***

Why does this happen?
I've even created this relation with Loopback relation generator. Same result. Can't figure out where is the error. Loopback doest see this relation. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can see the `model` is `User`, but I think you should be using `user` instead. Probably `User` model is not public and you have extended it to `user`.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. But I tried before "user" and it was same result :(

Answer (score 0):

It's all, because in model-config.json I have

```
  "TeamMember": {
    "dataSource": null,
    "public": true
  },
```

instead of:

```
  "TeamMember": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
```